# Is there a reason for removing spring mediator in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The WSO2 EI v6.6 removed the support for Spring Mediator. It was mentioned as 'deprecated' on v6.5 itself so the question is not about removal so much as about the reason for this removal.
Is there any specific reason for removing this mediator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have sent an update to WSO2 Architecture mailing list regarding deprecating this feature. Here is what included there.

```
| Feature                                    | Reason for deprecating                                                  |
|--------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Priority Executors, Enqueue Mediator       | Rarely used                                                             |
| Bean Mediator                              | Rarely used, no active development                                      |
| POJO Command Mediator                      | Rarely used, no active development                                      |
| Spring Mediator                            | Rarely used, no active development                                      |
| Conditional Router Mediator                | Same as Filter mediator, so no use of having this                       |
| In, Out Mediators                          | Rarely used, not required with the new call/respond mediator approach.  |
| Event Mediator & In memory Topics          | No real production usage                                                |
| ESB artifacts option in Management console | Rarely used                                                             |
```